# Right Angle Triangle Condition in Complex Numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, euclidean-geometry

Multiplying a complex number by $i$ results in rotating the number in the complex plane by $90$ degrees in the counter-clockwise direction.

I am attempting to apply this property to work with right triangles. Since the legs are perpendicular, if the vertex opposite the hypotenuse is the origin, then multiplying the second vertex by i should give the third.

Just an example, take the numbers
$$2+3i, 3+i$$

If I consider them to be two vertices of a right-angled triangle, and $z$ to to be the third vertex, then by a change of origin, and rotation, we must have
$$(2+3i)-z=i[(3+i)-z]\implies z=1.5 + 1.5i$$

This works, and is a right-angle. But I know that there should be an infinite number of right triangle that satisfy this condition (for example $2+i$ is one such).

Why did my equation give me only one solution? And what equation should I use to get all solutions?

**Edit:** As pointed out, the above equation is missing a scale factor. I tried this with scale factor $k$, and Mathway gave me:
$$(2+3i)-z=ki[(3+i)-z]\implies z=\frac{k+2+3i-3ki}{1-ki}$$

Isn't this very messy? Why is it so messy?

Comment: Multiplying by $i$ performs the $90^\circ$ rotation, but it makes the triangle's legs the same length. To stretch/shrink the rotated leg, multiply instead by, say, $\lambda i$ for an arbitrary real $\lambda$ (the scale factor). In your example, the solution $2+i$ corresponds to $\lambda=2$.

Comment: Your equation assumes the side lengths are equal. Multiply by $xi$ for any real $x$ and you still got a right triangle.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thanks.

Comment: That multiplying by $\mathrm{i}$ performs the $90^{\circ}$ rotation is not always true.
E.G. $0$ multiplying by $\mathrm{i}$:
$$0 \cdot \mathrm{i} = 0 \Rightarrow \arg(0 \cdot \mathrm{i}) = \arg(0) = 2 \cdot k$$.

Comment: I have seen zero defined to not have an argument. In any case, what is the value that you are assigning to the arg(0), and what is the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2):

This is correct, for the most part. When you multiply the first vertex by $i$ to achieve the second vertex via a rotation, you'll get a line with the exact same magnitude, in other words, you'd get an isosceles right-angle triangle every time. To fix that, consider multiplying the original vertex by $ai$ instead where $a$ is some real arbitrary constant (also called a scale factor in geometry).